# Book series about a young man who lives in a post-apocalyptic village where all technology is banned and he ends up in a futuristic city

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

The book series takes place in a post-apocalyptic world. I don't know how the world ended up like that.

The first book is about the main character who lives in a village where all use of technology is prohibited. He is kind of an outsider since he is always curious and the village elders don't like that. One day he finds an organ and repairs it and teaches himself how to play it. His music gets pretty dark at times and the towns people decide to destroy the organ. He kills his brother and runs away.

In one of the later books I don´t know if it is the second one or the third but anyway, I remember that he ends up in a large city made up of the mega-structures aligned in an triangle.  Each city has a different purpose: one for farming, one for military and defense and one for science. He end up in the science city where he becomes a clone engineer and makes some friends.

That pretty much sums up my memory of the books I think in the end he runs away again but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Could be the Tripods series by John Christopher?

Comment: In the Tripods series, there is no organ. Will doesn't repair anything; he does not kill any humans. There is no mention anywhere of the alien cities being specialized in function. Nobody becomes a clone engineer. So, no, that's not it.